# caret Error: Model is not in caret's built-in libraryModel

Tags: r, methods, r-caret

I'm trying to use multiple models present in Caret at the same time on a famous dataset: Iris. As a test I decided to take "Sepal.Length" as the target variable.

After running the following code I get this error:

"Error: Model gbm is not in caret's built-in libraryModel knn is not in caret's built-in libraryModel lm is not in caret's built-in libraryModel bstSm is not in caret's built-in libraryModel rf is not in caret's built-in library
In addition: Warning message:
In model == names (models):
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length "

```
mix_dataset_tra <-iris  
TrainIndex <- createDataPartition(mix_dataset_tra$Sepal.Length, p=0.75, list= FALSE) 
train <- mix_dataset_tra[TrainIndex,]  
test <-mix_dataset_tra[-TrainIndex,]  
trc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=3) 
AlgoritmListReg <- c("gbm","knn","lm","bstSm","rf")  
mixedModel<- caret::train(Sepal.Length~., data=train, method=AlgoritmListReg, trControl=trc)
```

Comment: Could you please share your code so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: mix_dataset_tra<-iris
TrainIndex <- createDataPartition(mix_dataset_tra$Sepal.Length, p=0.75, list= FALSE)
train<-mix_dataset_tra[TrainIndex,]
test<-mix_dataset_tra[-TrainIndex,]
trc<- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=3)
AlgoritmListReg<-c("gbm","knn","lm","bstSm","rf")
mixedModel<-caret::train(Sepal.Length~., data=train, method=AlgoritmListReg, trControl=trc)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to consider what your problem is: regression or classification. Not all models are suitable for both problems. You can check per algorithm on this [site](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) if your model is suitable for the type of problem. You can use the function `caretList` from `caretEnsemble` to perform multiple models in the `methodList` argument. I am not sure why, but when I add the model "bstSm" it doesn't work anymore, so here you have a reproducible example:

```r
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)
mix_dataset_tra<-iris 
TrainIndex <- createDataPartition(mix_dataset_tra$Sepal.Length, p=0.75, list= FALSE) 
train<-mix_dataset_tra[TrainIndex,] 
test<-mix_dataset_tra[-TrainIndex,] 
trc<- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=3) 
AlgoritmListReg<-c("rf", "lm", "knn", "gbm")
mixedModel <- caretEnsemble::caretList(Sepal.Length~., data=train, methodList=AlgoritmListReg, trControl=trc, verbose = FALSE)
resamples(mixedModel)
#> 
#> Call:
#> resamples.default(x = mixedModel)
#> 
#> Models: rf, lm, knn, gbm 
#> Number of resamples: 30 
#> Performance metrics: MAE, RMSE, Rsquared 
#> Time estimates for: everything, final model fit
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And you check the results from all models like this for example for "knn":

```
> mixedModel$knn
k-Nearest Neighbors 

115 samples
  4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 103, 104, 104, 103, 104, 103, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
  5  0.3506554  0.8171373  0.2975916
  7  0.3498502  0.8213085  0.2934273
  9  0.3566863  0.8138354  0.2966469

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 7.
```

Comment: Thanks Quinten! The only thing I don't understand is why it always chooses "rf" as the random forest algorithm even when I remove it from the methodList object. Could you help me?

Comment: @Quentin, were you able to get this code to work (and fit models based on each of the methods in `AlgoritmListReg`)? I got stuck trying to troubleshoot this (but it didn't seem like `methodList` was necessarily on track to me). Thanks!

Comment: @GaetanoC., I modified my answer! You can use the function `caretList` with argument `methodList` like above!

Comment: Hi @MichaelRoswell, I fixed the code! You can use the function `caretList` with `methodList` argument to train multiple models.

Comment: Finally works!. Thanks Quinten